# Встроить иконку в PHP код

Tags: php, html

Прошу помощи, не силён в PHP, прошу помощи.

Как встроить в php код иконку `<i class="las la-wallet"></i>` перед текстом перевода `$ULang->t("На модерации")`

```
function status($status=0){

    $ULang = new ULang();

     if($status == 0){
        return $ULang->t("На модерации");
     }elseif($status == 1){
        return $ULang->t("Активно");
     }elseif($status == 2){
        return $ULang->t("Снято с публикации");
     }elseif($status == 3){
        return $ULang->t("Заблокировано");
     }elseif($status == 4){
        return $ULang->t("Зарезервировано");
     }elseif($status == 5){
        return $ULang->t("Продано");
     }elseif($status == 6){
        return $ULang->t("Ждет оплаты");
     }elseif($status == 7){
        return $ULang->t("Отклонено");
     }elseif($status == 8){
        return $ULang->t("Удалено");
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно таким образом

```
function status($status=0){

    $ULang = new ULang();

    if($status == 0){
        return $ULang->t('<i class="las la-wallet"></i>На модерации');
    }elseif($status == 1){
        return $ULang->t("Активно");
    }elseif($status == 2){
        return $ULang->t("Снято с публикации");
    }elseif($status == 3){
        return $ULang->t("Заблокировано");
    }elseif($status == 4){
        return $ULang->t("Зарезервировано");
    }elseif($status == 5){
        return $ULang->t("Продано");
    }elseif($status == 6){
        return $ULang->t("Ждет оплаты");
    }elseif($status == 7){
        return $ULang->t("Отклонено");
    }elseif($status == 8){
        return $ULang->t("Удалено");
    }

}
```

А вообще этот код очень сложно поддерживать, если у вас появятся еще статусы то эта лапша из `if`ов будет расти, могу предложить как вариант переписать ее таким образом

```
function status($status = 0) {

    // индексы специально прописал для наглядности
    $messages = [
        0 => '<i class="las la-wallet"></i>На модерации',
        1 => 'Активно',
        2 => 'Снято с публикации',
        3 => 'Заблокировано',
        4 => 'Зарезервировано',
        5 => 'Продано',
        6 => 'Ждет оплаты',
        7 => 'Отклонено',
        8 => 'Удалено'
    ];
    $message = $messages[$status] ?? "Неизвестный код статуса";

    $ULang = new ULang();
    
    return $ULang->t($message);
}
```

**UPD** Если у вас эти фразы используются в качестве ключей для перевода то

```
function status($status=0){

    $ULang = new ULang();

    if($status == 0){
        return  '<i class="las la-wallet"></i>' . $ULang->t('На модерации');
    }elseif($status == 1){
        return $ULang->t("Активно");
    }elseif($status == 2){
        return $ULang->t("Снято с публикации");
    }elseif($status == 3){
        return $ULang->t("Заблокировано");
    }elseif($status == 4){
        return $ULang->t("Зарезервировано");
    }elseif($status == 5){
        return $ULang->t("Продано");
    }elseif($status == 6){
        return $ULang->t("Ждет оплаты");
    }elseif($status == 7){
        return $ULang->t("Отклонено");
    }elseif($status == 8){
        return $ULang->t("Удалено");
    }

}
```

И пример более удобного варианта

```
function status($status = 0) {

    // индексы специально прописал для наглядности
    $messages = [
        0 => [
            'text' => '<i class="las la-wallet"></i>На модерации',
            'prefix' => '<i class="las la-wallet"></i>'
        ],
        1 => 'Активно',
        2 => 'Снято с публикации',
        3 => 'Заблокировано',
        4 => 'Зарезервировано',
        5 => 'Продано',
        6 => 'Ждет оплаты',
        7 => 'Отклонено',
        8 => 'Удалено'
    ];

    $message = $messages[$status] ?? "Неизвестный код статуса";

    if(is_array($message)) {
        $message = $message['prefix'] . $message['text'];
    }
    
    $ULang = new ULang();

    return $ULang->t($message);
}
```

Comment: А если `ULang` это класс который переводит слова в зависимости от локали? И фразу `<i class="las la-wallet"></i>На модерации` он не сможет перевести?

Comment: @u_mulder Я только что про это же подумал и исправил ответ)

Comment: Огромное Вам СПАСИБО, Решили эту головоломку, для меня она огромная , для вас просто семечки ! Ещё раз спасибо, с уважением к Вам !!